# Send logs of libraries used in python to google cloud stackdriver logging

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I am writing a python script which uses pandas, numpy and other bunch of libraries. I am going to deploy this to google compute engine instance where the script will be run on a schedule using cron job. I am using google.cloud.logging to setup the logging so that cloud logging is attached to python root logger. However, if pandas raises an exception, I want the exception to go to stackdriver, which is not happening. How to do that? A workaround (ugly) is to put the main method (name == main) inside try, except Exception as e block and within except block, send the exception to cloud logging and reraise the exception so that script fails.
Is there a configuration that I am missing which can take care of this without try except?

Comment: Could you include the code you have written thus far that would better illustrate the situation and allow the community to attempt a reproduction (if needed)? This [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) should give you the information you need to improve your question.

Comment: See [Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting).

Answer (score 0):

For me it happened a similar situation. I didn't want to make a gigantic try/except using the `client.report()` method available in https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/python

So at last, what worked for me was implementing getSentry to send the logs to my email

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/

Install it with pip first:

`pip install --upgrade sentry-sdk`

And then, use this to capture the exceptions:

```
import sentry_sdk

sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn="https://examplePublicKey@o0.ingest.sentry.io/0",

    # Set traces_sample_rate to 1.0 to capture 100%
    # of transactions for performance monitoring.
    # We recommend adjusting this value in production.
    traces_sample_rate=1.0,
)
```